# Retain textbox value on return to same button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

The question look quite confusing but here is what i need, I use snipe IT ams application which is built on laravel framework.

I have a html page with a textbox and two radio button namely automatic and manual when user clicks on automatic button a php function is called and a random number is generated and the textbox field will become disabled on the other hand whenever a user clicks the manual button the textbox field must become enabled and the user can enter a value in the textbox field.

```
<script>
function CreateRandomNumber()
      {
        $('#asset_number').attr('value',("<?php CreateRandomNumber(); ?>"));
        $('#asset_number').attr('disabled','disabled');
      }
function EnableManualTextfield()
      {
        $('#asset_number').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#asset_number').val("");
      }
</script>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('asset_number') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="asset_number" class="col-md-3 control-label">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.number')</label>
                    <div class="controls col-md-7">
                        <input class="form-control assettext" type="text" name="asset_number" id="asset_number" value="{{ Input::old('asset_number', $assetdetail->asset_number) }}" />
                        {{ $errors->first('asset_number', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }} 
                        <input class="radio-button" type="radio" id="automatic" name="asset" onclick="CreateRandomNumber()" value="{{ Input::old('automatic',$assetdetail->automatic) }}" class="align-check1"> 
                               <label for="automatic" class="control-label">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.auto')</label>
                        <input class="radio-button align-check2 manualradio" type="radio" id="manual" name="asset" onclick="EnableManualTextfield()" checked="checked" value="{{ Input::old('manual',$assetdetail->manual) }}">
                               <label for="manual" class="manualtext">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.manual')</label>
                    </div>
   </div>

/* CreateRandomNumber Function */ 
/* This function is written seperately in a php file */

<?php

    function CreateRandomNumber() { 

        $letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $numbers = rand(100, 999999);
        $prefix = "SS-";
        $randomNumber = $prefix . $numbers ;
        echo $randomNumber;
    }

?>
```

Now the problem is whenever a user clicks on automatic a number is getting generated and if returned back to manual the text field gets enabled as expected, but i need do design it in such a way that if the user return backs to automatic button the pre-generated number must be display in the textfield.

Please note that the form is not yet submitted i need to store the generated random number in a variable and get the same number back when gets backs to the automatic field i do know how to achieve this please help me i am new to php and laravel.

Comment: Simply make a second (hidden) inputfield with the random number and when switching from manual to automatic copy the value.

Comment: @Michel can u please elaborate ur answer i couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value is not an attribute, so you have to change

```
$('#asset_number').attr('value',("<?php CreateRandomNumber(); ?>"));
```

into

```
$('#asset_number').val("<?php CreateRandomNumber(); ?>");
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thank you very much,very silly i didn't notice my mistake accepted your answer